# How can I smooth my seaborn heatmap plot in Python 3.6.0?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, smoothing, pylot

I have a seaborn heatmap plot like this:

[image]

With source code:

```
temp_cmap = ["#0416FF", "#0094FF", "#00DAFF", "#006600", "#00A305", "#71E507", "#DBF400", "#FFD602",
                 "#FF9B0F", "#FF1E01"]
sns.heatmap(df_grid, annot=False, cmap=temp_cmap, ax=self.axes_surface, cbar_ax=self.cbar_ax_1,
                        vmin=min_data,
                        vmax=max_data
                        )
```

But I want smooth this plot like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: matplotlib's [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolormesh-levels-py) seems to be interesting in your case.

Comment: Thanks JohanC. I would be insterested in your sugguest.

Comment: So, what's stopping you? Without data in text format and without some minimal demo code, it is hard to advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misusing the seaborn heatmap:)

The seaborn heatmap is just a colored table. Your desired result looks like you are trying plot things on a map. There are better ways of doing that. Try something like [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/index.html), [geoplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/index.html) or [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) (see a folium heatmap example [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Heatmap.ipynb)).

Comment: Yes, I have a shape file for this plot, but there is only one polygon. They created a grid 25 columns and 100 rows over that shapefile. So data that i have got from them that attached to each cell( row and column). There fore, I used seaborn heatmap for this plot. I would like to smooth that plot.